# "Sobbing in pain" OR "sobbing with pain"

Tags: prepositions

Both sounds correct to me:

> Sobbing **in / with** pain.
>
> Screaming **in / with** excitement.

What would native speakers prefer?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the verbs (screaming/sobbing) for a moment and just consider the nouns.

We normally say "I am *in* pain", not "with pain".

The verbs don't change this in any way. Someone who is "screaming in pain" is screaming *and* in pain. That said, this only really applies to the context of your example. There are other contexts where the reverse is true:

> I have been living with pain for 5 years.

"Excitement" is slightly different... I think either could be acceptable, it just depends on the context. Are you saying that that the person was *in* a state of excitement, or that the screaming was done *with* a sense of excitement? I would say that "*with* excitement" is far more common and idiomatic, but a quick Google shows that there are examples of both. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20excitement%2C%20with%20excitement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20excitement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20excitement%3B%2Cc0) confirms that "with excitement" is used far more in literature.

Comment: Hmm... the idea that for *either* of these, only one is acceptable isn't born out by the most easily accessible data... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=screaming+with+excitement%2Cscreaming+in+excitement%2Csobbing+in+pain%2Csobbing+with+pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscreaming%20with%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscreaming%20in%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csobbing%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csobbing%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "in pain" exists, but "in excitement" does not.

> - Yes:  I am in pain.
> - No:   I am in excitement.

These are all okay:

> - Sobbing in pain.
> - Sobbing with pain.
> - Screaming with excitement.

But not:

> - Screaming in excitement.

Comment: Hmm... the idea that for *either* of these, only one is acceptable isn't born out by the most easily accessible data... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=screaming+with+excitement%2Cscreaming+in+excitement%2Csobbing+in+pain%2Csobbing+with+pain&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscreaming%20with%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscreaming%20in%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csobbing%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csobbing%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"*Xing with Y*" is a pattern that is often used. In this case, the gerund-participle is *with* a noun that represents some sort of experience or emotional state - and you'll see it with *pain*, *excitement*, *pleasure*, *horror*, *dismay* and so on. It can be used, generally, with pretty much any such noun. It means that the noun has altered the character of the action described by the verb. It can also be used with other forms of the verb. The *with* element is just an adverbial:

> I looked at him with dismay.
>   She beamed at me with joy.

Here, the **manner of** the looking or beaming shows the emotional state or experience of the subject. It can also connote that the emotional state or experience is what has caused the action, but I would say it primarily connotes the emotional state or experience being apparent in the action.

You can also create the same sort of adverbial with *in*, and it conveys a similar meaning, but with the primacy of cause and effect on manner reversed. If I *scream in pain*, it suggests that the pain is what caused me to scream, with a secondary sense that the manner of the scream will somehow relate to being in pain.

Both forms exist and are used with a wide range of nouns, regardless of whether you could say "*I am in X*" or "*I am with X*", [as shown in this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_VERB_%20with%20excitement%2C_VERB_%20in%20excitement%2C_VERB_%20in%20pain%2C%20_VERB_%20with%20pain%2C%20_VERB_%20in%20terror%2C%20_VERB_%20with%20terror&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20terror%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20terror%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20pain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20in%20terror%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20with%20terror%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google ngram showing usage of in/with with pain, terror and excitement.]

Comment: What about "screaming out of pain"?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu I would consider that grammatical but not idiomatic. For the meaning I would read there, I would use "screaming due to pain" or "screaming from pain". They indicate a much more strongly causative meaning - the screaming is a result of the pain - and less of a sense that the character of the screaming is determined by the pain.